# log4j file randomly going to desktop

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, log4j

Here is my current log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger options. Where do we want to log to?
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, stdout, file

# define stdout log messages
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# define file log messages
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=src\\log.txt
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Note: I'm on a windows machine using tomcat which is why I use the `\\`.

This code works in another project. I see various similar answers here but nothing which addresses this specific problem.

For some reason, in this project specifically, it is creating an empty log.txt file in the appropriate directory within my project (%projectfolder%/src/log.txt) and then by some magic the actual log file is being created in a src folder on my desktop... so %desktop%/src/log.txt and it's writing the actual log there.

I have no idea why this is happening on my machine and it isn't happening to other people using the same code in my office. It's making me feel stupid and I can't figure it out. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks.

Comment: use log4j.appender.file.File=./src/log.txt

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I've tried that, but it still has the same problem. It just puts a new src/log.txt on my desktop and writes to that.

Comment: Your path is relative since it starts with a dot so the path will be built relative to the directory you are starting tomcat from or the user's default. Use an absolute path like c:\\project\\src\\log.txt

Comment: That does work. It's just so odd that it doesn't work as a relative directory for this but does for other people. Thanks. I'll just stick with the absolute path as a workaround and leave why it's placing an empty log file where it should be and one on my desktop which is actually used when relative as a mystery.

Comment: (Although now my code won't be portable if someone else needs to run it on their machine).

Comment: How do you start your programm? Do you have a batch file/shortcut/link to start it that is located on your desktop? Or maybe somehow you change the working dir to the desktop?

Comment: In eclipse, run on server (tomcat). No shortcut or anything like that, I run eclipse through the start menu.

Comment: Best advice I can think of is add logging to dump the current working directory so you can find out if somehow it really is set to your desktop. If it is not then I'd say your logging config is overridden by some other configuration somehow. Try comparing your environment to that of your coworkers, there has to be a difference somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. if we figure it out (might just move on) I'll post what the problem was and the solution so others can see if they come across the issue.